# foreach loop within SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array called $type which I need to put into an SQL query,

The problem is I dont know how many records $type will have when I submit the query...

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tutor_question WHERE questionId in (SELECT questionId FROM tutor_question_list_questions WHERE listId = " . $lid . ")";
```

Is there any way I can do a foreach loop within the query above to do something like this?

```
....AND
foreach ($type as $t) {
    echo $t;
}
```

I need to only extract the questions that fit the specific type I'm looking for.

I have tried a few combinations but cant get anything to work, can anyone help?

Comment: What column are you comparing `$type` to? Just use `IN ([list of values for $type])`

Comment: I have a column called "questionType". How would I use IN to do this?

Comment: I couldn't tell you how to use `in` without knowing the structure of your `$type` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"questionType IN (" . implode(",",$type) . ")"
```

You could do something along those lines, providing there is always at least one entry in type, if not you will need to check for this first

Comment: I really hope your `$type` array is properly escaped.